# Make a GIT repository read only for some users using gitosis

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, push, gitosis

We are running a GIT repository using gitosis and we need to forbid the push to some people of the team.

So i want everybody have read access to all repositories (got +10 repo and +20 machines where the users can do commit pull and push)

I need to restrict only the push, i want user can continue doing pull and clone but not push, only 2 users can push to master.

So any ideas? maybe to ask a password before make push?

Comment: sorry folks, in the rush i don't made my homework :(

Comment: As a sidenote, I would suggest moving to Gitolite, being more supported/featured/polite/sexy. But you probably heard that already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do this in the gitosis.conf file. Create two groups, one for those who can write to the repo, and one for those who have read-only access:

```
[repo my_repo]
description = Git repository for foobar
owner = user1

[group my-repo]
writable = my_repo
members = user1 user2

[group readonly]
readonly = my_repo
members = user3 user4 user5
```